# Insert Multiple data to mysql using a loop ...

Tags: php

so i have this code fragment here..

```
if($numTF > 0)
 {
echo "TRUE-AND-FALSE QUESTIONS: Enter them below followed by their correct answer.";
echo "<br>";?>
    <form method="post" action="" name="quizform">
<?php   for ($i=1; $i<=$numTF; $i++)
    { 
       echo "Question"." ".$i;
?>`


    <p><textarea name='question<?php echo $i; ?>' rows=3 cols=90></textarea></p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $i; ?>" value="True"> True &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type='radio' name="answer<?php echo $i; ?>" value="False"> False<br><br><br>
<?php           

             } 
}
```

... i am making a quiz maker in php...
the first thing to do is to set up the desired number of questions, so the value entered will go on the $numTF variable. Depending on the entered value, the textarea part will be printed. and there will be different names for each text area. AND THE CODE ABOVE IS WHERE U PRINT THE FORMS AFTER U ENTER THE DESIRED VALUE.
The next thing is to save that in a database. since the name of each textarea will be based on a variable value($i) that is used in a loop (name="answer") , HOW CAN I USE IT IN $_POST??? Like, would i do it like this?? ($_POST['question']).

HOW CAN I SAVE THESE QUESTIONS IN A DATABASE??
PLEASE HELP ME ....
I WOULD BE SO MUCH MUCH MUCH GRATEFUL FOR A LIL HELP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form method="post">
<?
$numTF=4;
if($numTF > 0)
 {
echo "TRUE-AND-FALSE QUESTIONS: Enter them below followed by their correct answer.";
echo "<br>";?>
    <form method="post" action="" name="quizform">
<?php   for ($i=1; $i<=$numTF; $i++)
    { 
       echo "Question"." ".$i;
?>`


    <p><textarea name='question[<?php echo $i; ?>]' rows=3 cols=90></textarea></p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="True"> True &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type='radio' name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="False"> False<br><br><br>
<?php           

  } 
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

Use $_POST['question'][1] // To get first question
Use $_POST['answer'][1] // To get first answer

Use loop to get all question and answers
```

Comment: That was simple ... ^^, THANK YOU SO MUCH!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sachin as far as using name='question[]'. To answer question a little more as far as storing it in a database. Personally I would use a JSON array.

```
$store_answers = json_encode($_POST['answer']);
$store_questions = json_encode($_POST['question']);
```

Then just store $store_string in a TEXT field in your database. Then when you pull it back out of the database you can simple use:

```
$answers = json_decode($store_answers);
$questions = json_decode($store_questions);
```

Then you can loop through using a foreach like so:

```
foreach($questions as $key=>$question) {
    echo "Question $key = {$answers[$key]} <br />";
}
```

This will display the results for each question.